# want to achieve zip in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I want to zip three columns in pyspark dataframe and iterate over it.
columns names: 'Id' ,'name' and 'percentile'
dataframe name: df

I have done already in pandas but not able to do so in pyspark
Pandas code as follows:

```
new=[]
for x in zip(df['Id'],df['name'],df['percentile']):
   lat_long = {'Id':x[0],'name':x[1],'percentile':x[2]}
   new.append(lat_long)
   print(new)
```

Comment: Your Pandas function returns a list of dictionaries. What do you want PySpark to return? If it is a dataframe, what data types? (Spark does not have neither list, not dictionary as its datatypes, you may need arrays or structs or maps). Please show us your expected output.

Comment: [{'Id': 31.23226, 'name': 77.52823, 'percentile': 85.58000183}]
[{'Id': 31.23226, 'name': 77.52823, 'percentile': 85.58000183}, {'Id': 31.23209, 'name': 77.5287, 'percentile': 186.1999969}]

Datatype is string type

Comment: Do you need this inside dataframe? In which column?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return the list of dictionaries, you don't need `zip`. You can `collect` all the Row objects and transform them into dictionaries using `.asDict()`.

Input dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(31.23226, 77.52823, 85.58000183),
     (31.23226, 77.52823, 85.58000183),
     (31.23209, 77.5287, 186.1999969)], 
    ['Id', 'name', 'percentile'])
df.show()
+--------+--------+-----------+
|      Id|    name| percentile|
+--------+--------+-----------+
|31.23226|77.52823|85.58000183|
|31.23226|77.52823|85.58000183|
|31.23209| 77.5287|186.1999969|
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Script:

```py
result = [r.asDict() for r in df.collect()]

print(result)
# [{'Id': 31.23226, 'name': 77.52823, 'percentile': 85.58000183}, {'Id': 31.23226, 'name': 77.52823, 'percentile': 85.58000183}, {'Id': 31.23209, 'name': 77.5287, 'percentile': 186.1999969}]
```